# Checking for cross-site scripting vulnerabilities in Perl web applications

Tags: security, perl

I'm putting together some notes for a dev team on how to write secure Perl code - especially taking into account the current OWASP top 10 web application vulnerabilities. For cross-site scripting I've included information on ensuring that all output to the browser is checked and escaped where necessary, but I'm looking for more automated mechanisms that would mean a developer doesn't have to think about every output statement and, potentially, miss one. Perl's 'taint' function sounds like it should be a help because it distrusts all user input, but it doesn't complain on tainted data being output to the browser. Apart from checking all output statements individually (probably by calling a generic sanitizing function) does anyone have any ideas on how Perl can help with this with existing libraries or techniques?

Comment: Good question, but I really think it should be on stack overflow or maybe security.se.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in how developers are writing programmatic solutions to this - i.e. what code might look like or consider. I agree it's partly about process, but it's more about hands-on development techniques I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the article [CERT Secure Coding Initiative Tackles Standard for Perl](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/newsitems/draft-perl-standard.cfm?wt.ac=hpFeature), the slides about [Perl::Critic for Security Audits](http://www.perloasis.info/opw2012/talk/3905), and [Perl::Critic](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl%3a%3aCritic) in general.

Comment: would you mind explaining what each of these resources does and what they're good for? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange